# PHP shmop segfault on reload

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I have a Proof-of-work (POW) timeout system made using js+html for the client, and php for the backend. I need to be able to store a cache of previously issued challenges, and i do this using shmop in php to store some stringified json into a mem cache. The issue i have ran into is that after a POW has been sent to the server, refreshing the index.html causes a segmentation fault.

## I suspect it is the php server itself, but I cannot confrim this

So far i have tried commenting out all the code in the php, still results in a seg fault. restarting my computer to clear the shmop cache still results in a seg fault. Maybe if there was an easier way to clear the cache other than from inside php itself then maybe i could make diagnosing it easier, but restarting my computer often is a lot of time.

`apt-get remove php; apt-get install php` also did not fix the seg fault

I had a friend git clone the `fix-segfault` branch and test it on his setup, and he was unable to recreate the same situation i have

SPECS:

BACKEND: PHP 7.2.9-1 Development Server

OS (uname -a): Linux kali 4.18.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2kali1 (2018-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux

FF: 60.3.0esr (64-bit)

Link for the files on github: https://github.com/dosisod/wasjs/tree/fix-segfault

The files only files I would see that might cause this error are `index.html`, `was.js` and `was.html`

Files are tooo looong to put in this post, but like I said before these may not even be the issue in the first place

Comment: Trying to make SHM work with PHP has never been anything other than an exercise in pain and sorrow. Why not use an actual caching product instead of trying to roll your own? There are plenty of [ready-to-use adapters](http://php-cache.com) out there.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed. I have looked into things like APC and APCu, but opted for shmop as it was built in and didnt require building/installing. Will look into that list in more detail later tonight, thanks!

Comment: No, [APCu is also a bad idea](https://medium.com/@davidtstrauss/avoiding-the-pitfalls-of-apcu-4aa9de00ef93). PHP [within the context of a web request] is not a daemon and you shouldn't treat it like one. SHM/APC segments more than likely won't persist between requests and trying to get around that will cost you your sanity and probably never work anyway. Use a cache _service_ like Redis or Memcache. Hell, you could probably get away with just using PHP Sessions.

Comment: Aaaa, My friend suggested using sessions to, yet there would be no way for me to verify that the challenge was a valid challenge, and not just the same one every time. Hence the need for server-side storage. Unless I used some sort of crypto then sessions arent doable, and doing my own crypto could be arguable worse but its worth looking into

Comment: Sessions _are_ server-side.

Comment: My god, i knew sessions used cookies but i presumed the data was also stored in the cookies, not on a temp directory on the server. Thanks @Sammitch and google